# Is it correct for me to consider using multi-processing for the following?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have a piece of code which retrieves the destination URLs of a series of stocks by going to the link in a sequential manner. I have read that multi-processing can be considered to speed up the entire process.

Any expert can explain what i could do to change the code to a multi-processing mode?

In my mind, If the code has to crawl to each destination URL sequentially, the bottle neck would be the access speed of the browser. Just wondering if using multi-processing is the way to speed it up because the program could spawn multiple version of the same code and go to 3-4 URLs at the same time and pass the result back to the code, etc.

```
index = 0
stop = len(stock) - 1
stockURL = {}
stockmap = {}

while index <= stop:
    tag = str(int(2) + index)
    if index <= 7:
        w.iimPlayCode(path to my file)
        w.iimPlayCode('WAIT SECONDS=5')
        w.iimPlayCode('ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}')
        stockURL[index] = w.iimGetExtract(1)
        w.iimPlayCode('BACK')        
        index +=1
    else:
        w.iimPlayCode(path to my file)
        w.iimPlayCode('WAIT SECONDS=5')
        w.iimPlayCode('ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}')
        stockURL[index] = w.iimGetExtract(1)
        w.iimPlayCode('BACK')
        index += 1  

stockURL = list(stockURL.values())
stockURL = str(u','.join(stockURL))
stockURL = stockURL.replace('http', 'URL GOTO=http').split(',')
stockURL = list(stockURL)

stockmap = dict(zip(stocks, stockURL))
```

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/, which has an example of how to do basically what you're looking for - query multiple URLs in parallel as opposed to in sequence. It's a good read :)